# Will "delete this" in a base class pointer delete the derived class object when you have a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, oop, object, virtual-destructor

I have a class hierarchy that's three levels deep, like this:

```
class A {
public: 
    virtual ~A() {}

}

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
    void foo(E *e) {
        e->remove(this);
    }
}

class C : public B {
public:
    ~C() {}
}

class E {
public:
    void remove(A *a) {
        delete a;
    }
}
```

Ok so what I am wondering is what happens when I call `foo()` on an object of `C`. Is it going to remove the entire object or only the `B` and `A` part of the object, and leave the `C` part still in memory?

Comment: You have syntax errors. Please fix them. Also, avoid `delete this` like the plague. Also, `void remove(A* a)` in `class E`, but `void remove(E* e)` in `class B`? Are you sure? Yikes!

Comment: You are destroying all the object, and releasing its memory.

Comment: There are 2 removes in your code. Which one?

Comment: Virtuality of destructors is hereditary.

Comment: Try access a method of an instance of class B after you removed A is an alternative way of checking this.

Comment: Syntax errors fixed, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it going to remove the entire object or only the B and A part of the object, and leave the C part still in memory?

No. It will "do the right thing" (that is, delete the most derived subobject, run all its destructors etc.) provided `A` (that is, the static type of the pointee of the pointer you `delete`) has a virtual destructor (and if class `A` has a virtual destructor, all its descendants have it, too). This holds for multiple inheritance, too.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the virtual destructor in `A` the code would work correctly destroy the entire instance of `C`.

Comment: Is this true for all compilers? I swear I have seen C destroyed without A having declared a virtual destructor. Mainly in gcc.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` will always release the memory for the whole object pointed to.
This doesn't apply to called destructors however: It will try to call the destructor of the static type of the object to delete. 
In a polymorphistic scenario, this is often not what you want. Consider this:

```
struct Base { };

struct Derived : Base
{
    int* i;

    Derived() : i(new int) { }

    ~Derived() { delete i; }
}

void bad()
{
    Base* b = new Derived;
    delete b;
}
```

`bad()` causes a memory leak, because `Derived`s destructor will never be called. This is because the static type of b is `Base*`, thus `Base::~Base` will be called. There is no destructor defined in `Base`, so the default implementation provided by the compiler executes, which does nothing in this particular example.

This however does not apply to your example: You made the root class' destructor virtual, so all derived classes' destructors will be executed as part of the destructor call.